# correlation implies dependency?

Tags: probability, correlation, independence, causality

In this talk from prof Bernhard https://youtu.be/4qc28RA7HLQ?t=88

he only sees/shows linear correlation, and he assumes there is ‘dependency’?

Correct me if wrong but correlation does not imply ‘dependency’ so why is he  implying it?

https://youtu.be/4qc28RA7HLQ?t=88

Comment: Correlation does not imply *causality*, but dependence / independence is a different concept.

Answer (score 2):

From purely probabilistic perspective, if two random variables are correlated, they can't be statistically independent, i.e. $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\neq0\rightarrow X\not\perp Y$. But, if the correlation/covariance is $0$, those variables can still be dependent. So, presence of correlation implies dependence between random variables; but the presence of dependence doesn't imply correlation.